# My Code coverage is just 3%. How can i improve it?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

My code coverage is just 3%. How to improve code coverage for this class?

My Class:

```
 @future
    public static void assignContacts(List<Id> accIds){
        List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, Account__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accIds];
        if (accounts != null && accounts.size() > 0){
            Map<Id, Id> accToOwner = new Map<Id, Id>();
            for (Account a: accounts){
                if (!accToOwner.containsKey(a.Id)){
                    accToOwner.put(a.Id, a.OwnerId);
                }
            }

            List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :accIds];
            List<Contact> contactsForUpdate = new List<Contact>();

            for (Contact c: contacts){
                if (accToOwner.containsKey(c.AccountId) &&
                    accToOwner.get(c.AccountId) != c.OwnerId){
                    c.OwnerId = accToOwner.get(c.AccountId);
                    contactsForUpdate.add(c);
                }
                if (contactsForUpdate.size()>= 50){
                    update contactsForUpdate;
                    contactsForUpdate.clear();
                }
            }

            if (contactsForUpdate.size() > 0){
                update contactsForUpdate;
            }
        }
    }
```

My Test Class:

```
public static testmethod void TestforassignContacts(){
        List<Account> acc = [select id, OwnerId, AccountId__c from account limit 1];
        if(acc != NULL){
        Map<Id, Id> accToOwner = new Map<Id, Id>();
        accToOwner.put(acc.id,acc.OwnerId);

        List<Contact> c = [select id from contact where AccountId=: a[0].id limit 2];

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't remove your code from your question after getting an answer. The code in your original question provides important context to the answers that you get. Questions and answers here are as much for you as they are for other people with similar problems, and removing context from your question makes it hard for others to learn from your tribulations.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how you have three percent, since you do not call or invoke your code under test in any way. Fundamentally, you have to execute the code in order to get test coverage, and then you should be making assertions to demonstrate that your code did what you thought it would. That's the essence of a unit test, as opposed to a "smoke test" (which doesn't prove anything at all except that your code doesn't crash).

Your test is going to need to set up dummy data for your code to find, and then call `assignContacts()` within a `Test.startTest()`/`Test.stopTest()` pair, because it's a future method. (This forces it to run synchronously).

You should then query against your test data to pull in the updates that that method makes and call methods like `System.assert()` and `System.assertEquals()` to show that the results are as you expect them to be.

You may wish to complete the [Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_testing/units/apex_testing_intro) on unit testing, and read through the [three-part series](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/05/why-we-test.html) on unit testing on the Salesforce Developer blog. [How To Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests) is also a great reference.

Answer (score -2):

You need to create test data for Account,contact and test user.

Profile pf= [Select Id from profile where Name='System Administrator']; 
User usr=new User();
usr.firstname = 'ABC';
usr.lastName = 'XYZ';
usr.ProfileId = pf.Id,
insert usr;
system.AssertEquals('ABC',usr.name);

Account a=new Account();
a.name='Test acc';
a.ownerid=usr.id;
insert a;

contact c=new contact();
c.lastname='test last';
c.accountid=a.id;
insert c;
c.ownerid=a.ownerid;
update c;